# What's the easiest way to serialize entire gameobjects or only of components [unity 3d]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What's the easiest way to serialize entire gameobjects or only of components ? ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO. One line question is not good. Please explaining what you are doing and why you need to serialize a GameObject....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `[Serializable]` before the `public class yourClass`.  Then do something like this to serialize the data:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream file = File.Create ("savefile"); //you can call it anything you want
bf.Serialize(file, GameObjectToBeSerialized);
file.Close();`
```

Here's some documentation, the first is to the unity source on how to do these and then to the unity's community forum.
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/967840/saving-your-scene-and-location-in-game.html